# Why does "I don't have a girlfriend yet" sound better than "I haven't had a girlfriend yet?"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses

I feel like the first one sounds better but I can't explain why

Comment: The former means that you don't currently have a girlfriend, the latter means that you've never had one.

Comment: @MorganFR - No, the latter means you haven't "HAD" a girlfriend.  There's a big difference between "had" and "HAD".

Comment: @HotLicks You just wrote the same word "had" twice. Capitalizing it doesn't make it another word.

Comment: @MorganFR - That's what you think.  You can have a girlfriend and not have HAD her yet.

Comment: @HotLicks I suppose you mean in the biblical sense. I still wouldn't write it with capital letters, but eventually use (air) quotes or a different tone. Regardless I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP had in mind

Comment: I could have written it in italics, I suppose.  It's all in how you say it.  But "I haven't had a girlfriend yet" implies that meaning.

Comment: What is alluded to above is that in many English dialects to 'have' someone is slang for to have sex with them.

Comment: Ok, it's off topic, but I have to admit I'm somewhat amused by @HotLicks...

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't had a girlfriend yet.

I've never had a girlfriend.

> I don't have a girlfriend yet.

I don't currently have a girlfriend, and have not since some understood point in time (since your last girlfriend, or since school started, or whatever implied timeline the conversation may entail).

Both are correct in given circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the premise that the first sentence sounds better.  Grammatically, I would suggest it is confused!

- “I haven't had a girlfriend yet?” is absolute for all time... you haven't had a girlfriend yet.
- “I don't have a girlfriend yet” mixes a current tense ("I don't have") with a past-tense modifier ("yet")

I would suggest that a more correct present tense sentence would be (something like) “I don't have a current girlfriend” or “I don't have a girlfriend, now”

Comment: Both still are grammatically correct in certain circumstances... for example, responding to the question "Did you find a date yet for our double-date on Monday?"

Comment: no need to answer or comment on questions that should be closed

Comment: _Yet_ is not a past-tense modifier. It works just as well with the present as the past. Both of your suggested rephrasings mean something altogether different.